# Creating an editable area in Microsoft Word 2010 document

Tags: ms-word, ms-office

I am sure this should be simple, however I have had a look around and drawn an blank. I have a requirement to create a Word template which is locked down for editing, except for an area in the body of the document. So for example, the document may be something like...

Dear Sir,

[Editable Region]

Regards,
Mr ABC

Is this possible? The editable region should allow any standard Word features, e.g. images, tables, track changes, etc.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for this same thing and came across a link that explained it.  Try here: http://www.mademan.com/mm/how-create-editable-forms-word-2010.html

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the developer tab:
There are some buttons in there that will add text boxes and other form elements:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MSaDE.png)

If you don't have the developer tab, do this first:
Go to options and "Customize Ribbons", make sure "Developer" is ticked.